# SSRS Row Sorting

Tags: sorting

I have a matrix report like this

route    Friday    Sunday   Wednesday   Tuesday   Saturday  Thursday   Monday

van1     jlsjdf    sdf      dfsdf       sfsd      sdfs      sf         sdfs
         sdfs
         sdf

Days above are non grouped, now i want these days to come like this in sequence

route    Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday   Thursday   Friday  Saturday   Sunday

What should i do Plz help
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say they are non-grouped, if each day is not a group and is an individual column then you can just re-arrange the columns on the tablix to suit.

However I suspect that your days is a column group, then if so on the column Group Properties click the Sorting tab and enter in the following expression:

```
Switch(Fields!Day.Value="Monday",Fields!Day.Value="Tuesday",2,Fields!Day.Value="Wednesday",3,Fields!Day.Value="Thursday",4,Fields!Day.Value="Friday",5,Fields!Day.Value="Saturday",1,Fields!Day.Value="Sunday",1,)
```

This converts each day into a number and it is then sorted based on this number.

This is useful when you want custom sort orders, you just need to convert the values into a sequence order using a switch statement then you can sort in numerical order.

Comment: Thank you Tom Jenkin this is exactly what i wanted, and you were right, i meant not a row group but it is a column group in my matrix report, thank you once again

Comment: I have another problem, Please go to my profile and have a look into it, if you have any question plz ask me, Thank You